# Why is the induced voltage due to the current of the phase conductor wrapped around the shield not included in the inducedvoltage calculation formula?

Tags: voltage

Why is the induced voltage due to the current of the phase conductor wrapped around the shield not included in the voltage calculation formula induced by the shield/sheath in the three-phase coaxial cable?

As shown in the equation below, the voltage induced in the a-phase shield/sheath surrounding the a-phase conductor is only due to the b-phase and c-phase conductor current.

Why is there no induced voltage due to a-phase conductor current?

[image]

[image]

The picture is from http://www.jicable.org/2007/Actes/Session_B9/JIC07_B97.pdf.

And IEEE-575-2014 AnnexD also converted the expression using the 120 degree rotation operator a, but the result is the same expression.

https://dokumen.tips/documents/575-2014-ieee-guide-for-bonding-shields-and-sheaths-of-single-conductor-power.html

The equation of the a-phase shield/sheath induced voltage above is converted to the following.

[image]

Obviously, there is only the induced voltage due to the b-phase conductor current and the c-phase conductor current. Why was the induced voltage due to the a-phase conductor current not considered?

Comment: I have no idea what a, b, and c mean here. Do you have a source for your equations?

Comment: It's probably just an approximation/omission to simplify the calculations. Mutual inductance between two wires increases (logarithmically) with increasing distance between them, while self-inductance of a single wire does not depend on that distance, and thus mutual inductance can dominate the self-inductance if distance between the wires is large enough. Self-inductance is also hard to express correctly, it is not linear in conductor length. Both reasons make people ignore self-inductance. Whether the effect of self-induction can really be ignored depends on details of the case.